# Backbone.js adding sub-view elements to parent-view's element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection view and a model view, like so:

```
EventListView
|-- EventView
```

`EventListView` must display many `EventViews` in a one-to-many relationship. I am using the underscore `_.template()` function to build my views templates.

Here is my `EventView` template:

```
<h1>
    <span class="date"><%= prefix %><%= dateString %></span>
    <span class="title"><%= title %></span>
</h1>
<div class="caption"><%= caption %></div>
```

My `EventView` render method:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
}
```

And here is my `EventListView` template:

```
<h1>
    <% if(typeof(title) != "undefined") { print(title) } %>
</h1>
<%= events %>
```

And it's render method:

```
// this._EventViews is an array of eventView objects
render: function() {

    var templateData = {
        events: _.reduce(this._EventViews, function(memo, eventView) { return memo + eventView.$el.html(); }, "")
    }
    this.$el.html(this.template(templateData));
    return this;
}
```

The problem I am having is that `eventView.$el.html()` contains only the HTML in my template, but I need to take advantage of the `tagName`, `className` and `id` attributes that Backbone views support.

Consider if I set up `EventView` like so:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({

    model: EventModel
,   tagName: 'article'
,   className: 'event'  
,   template: _.template(templateText)

,   render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
```

I want to insert:

```
<article class="event" id="someID342">
    <h1>
       <span class="date">01/02/2010</span>
       <span class="title"></span>
       <div class="caption></div>
    </h1>
</article>
```

but `eventView.$el` returns:

```
<h1>
   <span class="date">01/02/2010</span>
   <span class="title"></span>
   <div class="caption></div>
</h1>
```

How do I insert the entire `eventView` element? Not just it's `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reserve placeholder in your EvenListView's template

```
<h1><%- title %></h1>
<div class="js-events"></div>
```

And then render and append child views

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({title: 'Title'}));
    this.$events = this.$('.js-events');
    _.each(this._EventViews, function (eventView) {
        this.$events.append(eventView.render().$el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `render()` function shouldn't be responsible for handling the setup of the `view.el`. This is done by `Backbone` in the `_ensureElement` function that is called when you initialize the view.

Also, the [`$.fn.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function is only supposed to return the contents of the selected element.

Comment: The render function is just used to draw it on the page and I know that `$.fn.html()` returns the contents, but what I'm asking is how to draw the entire thing. All the render function does is grab the template, evaluate it and draw it. All things I only want to happen at render time.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options but I think the most flexible and sustainable approach is to get each sub view to define its own template.  The parent view simply appends the child elements `.el` property.

The advantages of this approach, your template is only compiled once.  And updates to children do not require re-rendering parent and neighbouring elements.

Here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vecive/1/edit?js,output)

### Example:

```js
var ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: "article",
  className: "event",
  id: "someID342",

  initialize: function(options){
    //the template will now be rendered
    this.childView = new ChildView()

    //the rendered child will now appear within the parent view
    this.el.appendChild( this.childView.el )
  }

})

var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName: "h1",
  dateString:"01/02/2010",
  prefix: "Date: ",
  caption: "What a wonderful date!:",
  title: "I am a title",
  template: _.template([
    '<h1>',
      '<span class="date"><%= prefix %><%= dateString %></span>',
      '<span class="title"><%= title %></span>',
    '</h1>',
    '<div class="caption"><%= caption %></div>'
  ].join("")),

  initialize: function(){
    this.render()
  },

  render: function(){
    // because you are only altering innerHTML
    // you do not need to reappend the child in the parent view
    this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this)
  }

})
```

I'd personally caution against using templates in Backbone at all.  I've found that simply having a Backbone view for every component of your app becomes a lot easier to edit later.  Sharing templates is a lot harder than sharing views.  Of course it depends on the requirements of your project.